# Setting the base tag of a dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, tags, radix

I'm trying to dynamically create an iframe and set it's base tag before it is created.

```
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "test.html"); 
ifrm.style.width = 400+"px"; 
ifrm.style.height = 100+"px"; 

//before creating it, can we set he base tag?
//I.E. <base href="http://example.com/MyFolder/" />
var bt = ifrm.contentDocument.createElement("base");
bt.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/Folder/");
ifrm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bt);

document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

I know i can set the base tag in the iframes src file itself. But I need to set it here.
Thanks.

Comment: I am still unable to get this working.  Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append a `<base>` element to `ifrm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")`.

You'll need to create it in the child document by calling `ifrm.contentDocument.createElement("base")`

For example:

```
var bt = ifrm.contentDocument.createElement("base");
bt.setAttribute(...);
ifrm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bt);
```

Comment: base = document.createElement("base");    is this the correct place to start?

Comment: No, because you need to create it in the child document

Comment: I'm still alittle lost,  can ya show me a little example code to help out?

Comment: ifrm.contentDocument does not exist until ifrm is appended. hmmm